# Making backup from database to another server

Tags: sql-server, backup, linked-server, distributed-database

I have a host on a server and that contains an SQL Server Database.
I have another server in another country and i want have a backup from the database every 5 minutes or after each transaction only insert new row to another database.
After some research i found out i can use `linkedservers` for this goal.
Is this procedure works for me for doing this operation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the linkedserver will do for you.

You are connected from both server via a vpn?
You are in different network (domain) probably?

If you are using a linked server, it means you will probably create trigger or stored proc. You will have to configure msdtc (for trigger).

You can use :

- Replication
- Log shipping
- Custom replication process

I had to configure 2 times a replications to move the data from a server to another, than manage these data with trigger. It was easier to work on the data localy

Comment: You are exactly right , i have different server , with different domains.if i have problem with server A , i want to use server B, but i need the databases are synced with each other.